# Flutter Floor "duplicate column name"

Tags: sql, flutter

I'm facing this exact error using the Floor package in Flutter `Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "duplicate column name: kit"`  and I can't see exactly where i've made a mistake, here's my full database code:

The error happens when I currently have version 5 of the database running and I attempt to run a build of the project that has version 6.

```
    @Database(version: 6, entities: [Player, SavedTeam, Design, Kit, KitPattern])
abstract class LocalDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  PlayerDao get playerDao;

  SavedTeamDao get savedTeaDao;

  DesignDao get designDao;

  KitDao get kitDao;

  KitPatternDao get kitPatternDao;
}

final migration1to2 = Migration(1, 2, (database) async {
  await database.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SavedTeam` '
      '(`id` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `pitchFilePath` TEXT NOT NULL,'
      ' `playerOne` TEXT NOT NULL,'
      ' `playerTwo` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerThree` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerFour` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerFive` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerSix` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerSeven` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerEight` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerNine` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerTen` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerEleven` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerOneOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerTwoOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerThreeOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerFourOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerFiveOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerSixOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerSevenOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerEightOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerNineOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerTenOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `playerElevenOffset` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `kitColor` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `pitch` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      'PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');
});

final migration2to3 = Migration(2, 3, (database) async {
  await database.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Design` '
      '(`id` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `pattern` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `patternColor` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `baseKitColor` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      'PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');

  await database.execute('ALTER TABLE SavedTeam ADD COLUMN design TEXT');
  await database.execute('ALTER TABLE SavedTeam ADD COLUMN showPhotos INTEGER');
});

final migration3to4 = Migration(3, 4, (database) async {
  await database.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Kit` '
      '(`id` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `productId` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `assetPath` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      'PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');
});

final migration4to5 = Migration(4, 5, (database) async {
  await database.execute('ALTER TABLE SavedTeam ADD COLUMN kit TEXT');
});

final migration5to6 = Migration(5, 6, (database) async {
  await database.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `KitPattern` '
      '(`id` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `productId` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      ' `assetPath` TEXT NOT NULL, '
      'PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');
});

final localDatabase = $FloorLocalDatabase
    .databaseBuilder('local_database.db')
    .addMigrations([
  migration1to2,
  migration2to3,
  migration3to4,
  migration4to5,
  migration5to6
]).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't figure out exactly why SQL was attempting to run an old migration (4 to 5) I have fixed the issue by wrapping the migration in a try catch like so:

```
final migration4to5 = Migration(4, 5, (database) async {
  try {
    await database.execute('ALTER TABLE SavedTeam ADD COLUMN kit TEXT');
  } on Exception {
    print("migration 4to5 error");
  }
});
```